# add image from value

Tags: reactjs, image

I have this call to component

```
<Card card={card} path={putPicture(card)} />

function putPicture(card) {
  const pic =  require()`../../../assets/cat.jpg`); // <== this works

  // const pic =  require(card.path);  <== this not 
  return card.path;
}
```

I'm trying to add this picture, but I'm getting an error:

> **Invalid call at line 146: require(card.path)**

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a known problem, basically packager does not support that.  take a look at the answer here you can have better understanding, https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6391. Quoted from the link

Based on how the packager works, this isn't really possible with require.
Packaging happens once before runtime so those variables don't have values yet.